# Yii2 : Setting Access Control filter to redirect after forbidden

Tags: authentication, yii2

I have a controller that use `AccessControl` in behaviors function like this :

```
public function behaviors()
    {       
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['login', 'error'],
                        'allow' => true,
                    ],
                    [
                        'actions' => ['logout', 'index'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                        'matchCallback' => function(){
                            return (Yii::$app->user->identity->ROLE_ID=='1');
                        }
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
```

In my application there a 2 role, **admin** and **user**, role_id 1 is admin and role_id 2 is staff, both can access `/app/administrator` so I filter with that. And when I log in with staff, it shows forbidden page.

I want to redirect back in log in page when the user that log in isn't admin. Maybe I must add script in `AccessControl` options. So, what can i do? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify [`denyCallback`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-accesscontrol.html#$denyCallback-detail) to achieve this.

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
               //your access rules
            ],
            'denyCallback' => function($rule, $action) {
                 //redirection here
            }
        ],
    ];
}
```

Note that this `denyCallback` will be called every time when access is denied. If you want rule-specific `denyCallback` e.g. you want different application behavior, then you need to specify it like this:

```
'rules' => [
    //other rules
    [
        'actions' => ['index'],
        'allow' => false,
        'roles' => ['@'],
        'matchCallback' => function(){
            return (Yii::$app->user->identity->ROLE_ID == 2);
        },
        'denyCallback' => function(){
            //redirect here
        }
    ],
],
```

Here we explicitly disallow access to *index* action to users with `ROLE_ID == 2` and redirecting them.